# How to disable integrated Avast antivirus inside EMUI 5.0 (Android 7.0)?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, antivirus

### I have the following phone:

Honor 8; FRD-L09

- [Official website](http://www.hihonor.com/global/products/mobile-phones/honor8/index.html)
- [Information about integrated Avast antivirus inside EMUI 5.0](https://club.hihonor.com/in/tips.267/span-stylecolorredscanspan-your-phone-with-span-stylecolorredvirusspan-span-stylecolorredscanspan-and-get-rid-of-span-stylecolorredvirusspan-in-it.12379)
- Picture with basic information:

[image: Honor 8 basic information]

---

### Picture with integrated Antivirus from Phone Manager (Virus scan):

[image: integrated Antivirus from Phone Manager]

### Once I click on the Virus scan, I get a very quick scan with the Avast logo at the bottom:

[image: Avast logo at the bottom]

---

### Important note:

As this device is new and under warranty, I cannot root it.

### Intention:

I have my own trusted antivirus solution, it does not matter which one at this point.

I want to use it instead of the integrated Avast solution.

### Question:

How to disable integrated Avast antivirus inside EMUI 5.0 (Android 7.0) ?

I called various local support lines, but to no avail.

In settings there is no available option as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible , given the fact that it is integrated into the phone manager application, and is also a **system application**.

I also have a Huawei tablet (*EMUI 1.6*)  which also has a tablet manager (package name `com.huawei.systemmanager`) but has a storage cleaning option which is said to be **powered by Du Speed Booster**. However I did several scans to try and find the app to no avail.

So I think it is not possible to separate the antivirus functionality from the phone manager app, so you either remove the whole phone manager package (if rooted that is) or stay with it. Otherwise I doubt if you cant explicitly find the avast as a package in your system.

You can still install another AV solution of your choice - (it really unnecessarily strains the phone resources) **besides  I don't see the use of Antiviruses in android, if you obtain your applications from official trustworthy sources**.

[image: hwsys mgr]

*Huawei tablet manager (Storage cleaning functionality powered by Du Speed booster)*